# What is the formatting shown on the ribbon (Home tab, Font section), pertain to, at any given insertion point?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

I have the following hyperlinked, superscripted text for reference citation note:

> (23)

When I select the first character in the brackets (2), the Font section on the Home ribbon reads **Segoe UI**, **9**, **Underlined**, **Superscripted**.

When I select the second character in the brackets (3), the formatting info is the same.

However, when I select both characters together, formatting info vanishes on the ribbon!

Why is that?

Moreover, for a different 2-character hyperlink; the formatting info being reported is the same when I select each character separately. But when I **just leave the cursor in between the 2 characters**, the formatting again vanishes!!

Why is that?

Comment: I can upload the Word document, but it's sprinkled with lots of hyperlinked reference numbers.
I lost track of which one of them is exhibiting the second behavior...

Comment: Please do when you figure it out. It is likely that the formatting was applied separately to each character.